# Date-picker styles not working after production build in Angular 4

Tags: angular, datepicker, ngx-bootstrap

recently I created a build of my Angular5 app in which I used ngx-bootstrap to show datepicker and modals. It was working very well before production, but after production, build seems like it lost its styling.

please check attached image...

[image]

I followed all the implementation steps again, but nothing worked.

Please help to resolve this issue. Thank you so much.

Comment: Did you try to use the Chrome inspector on your dev and prod sites to see if there is a difference in the markup or styles between the two sites? Did you look in the package-lock.json files to see if they are using the exact same versions?

Comment: Hi Daniel, I did mostly everything to make it happen, finally got a solution to load css initially.  BTW, thanks for attention and help mate :)

Comment: This is because, the datepicker provided by ngx-bootstrap is not the same as the one provided by bootstrap, so you need additional styles.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Finally, I found a solution.

I just added ngx-bootstrap CSS into `angular-cli.json`

**angular-cli.json**

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css"],
```

and it worked for me. Thanks for attention.

Comment: thank you. worked for me too..

Jus check the path of node modules in terms of your angular-cli.json and add the path. for me it was: "node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css"

Answer (score 3):

an other solution can solve your problem if the previous solution doesn't :

it's for : 
 `"@angular/core": "^6.0.3", "@angular/material": "^7.3.2",`

first add bs-datepicker.css path to angular.json file in the style paths :

```
"styles": [
    "styles.css",
    "../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css"],
```

if you add bs-datepicker.css and still doesn't work try to add this link to your style.css

```
@import "~node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker.css";
```

[image]

that solved the problem for me hope it helps !

Answer (score 0):

Another solution would be adding the CSS to your assets directory.

Answer (score 0):

For Angular 10 and ngx version-6.2.0

This happens when we use
`npm install ngx-bootstrap --save`
this command.

Try using this
`ng add ngx-bootstrap`

But before that use npm uninstall if you have used the first command.

Answer (score 0):

```
@import '../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import "../node_modules/ngx-bootstrap/datepicker/bs-datepicker";
```

Add above things in *`src/styles.scss`*